# Position a row at center in XDK

Tags: android, html, css, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK to build an app with app designer.
I've got a login screen info (UID, PWD and Login Button) inside a row.

Now I want this row to appear at screen center(horizontal and vertical), irrespective of screen size.

Do I have to do this with media query with different sizes or there is any other way of doing this without using the media queries ?

code :

```
<div class="upage background" id="mainpage">
            <div class="upage-outer">
                <div class="uib-header header-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_1" data-uib="layout/header" data-ver="0">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="upage-content content-area vertical-col" id="page_92_17">

                    <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_1 space" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="col uib_col_1 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                            <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                                <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="1">
                                    <label class="narrow-control"></label>
                                    <input class="wide-control form-control default" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                                </div>
                                <div class="table-thing widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/input" data-ver="1">
                                    <label class="narrow-control"></label>
                                    <input class="wide-control form-control default" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn widget uib_w_5 d-margins btn-primary" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1">Login<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right button-icon-right" data-position="right"></i>
                                </button><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="uib-footer uib-footer-fixed footer-bg container-group inner-element uib_w_2" data-uib="layout/footer" data-ver="0">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
                    <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your row/column inside another row/column. Then, in the outer column, set its alignment to "Center Vertical and Horizontal".  And change the min-height of the outer row to 100% (or 100vh).  You can do all of that from within App Designer.

That should do it.

Chris